# Java regex. Why this is false (eclipse expression debugger)

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Why this returns false?

```
"$10+".matches("^\\\\${0,1}[1-9,\\\\.]{0,}[\\\\+kK]{0,}")
```

I use eclipse debugger so this is the reason to use `\\\\` instead of `\\`

first sign matches to `^\\\\${0,1}`
numbers or comma or dot matches to `[1-9,\\\\.]{0,}`
last sign + or k or K should match `[\\\\+kK]{0,}`

But returns false. Why?

Comment: `[1-9,\\\\.]{0,}` matches the 1 but not the 0 that follows it. I guess you want `0-9` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't zero in the set, it should probably be:

```
"$10+".matches("^\\${0,1}[0-9,\\.]{0,}[\\+kK]{0,}"
```

or maybe (if you want to have non-zero at the beginning):

```
"$10+".matches("^\\${0,1}[1-9\\.][0-9,\\.]{0,}[\\+kK]{0,}"
```

Additionally, it's not needed to escape + in the character group, not sure about the same for "." .

Comment: You right! Looks like I need to rest for a while :)

Comment: Why escape a plus inside a character class? `[\\+]` -> `[+]`. `{0,1}` = `?`

Answer (score 0):

I tested with JUnit your expression.

```
@Test
public void testRegex() throws Exception {
    assertTrue("$10+".matches("^\\${0,1}[0-9,\\\\.]*[\\\\+kK]*"));
}
```

It is returning true now. And I change your optionals {0,} by *.